# Spliting a PolygonSprite in two gives wrong rotation + offset?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to achieve a split effect similar to Fruit Ninja, but the object has to be cut where the user swipes. I followed [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/08/05/slicing-splitting-and-cutting-objects-with-box2d-part-4-using-real-graphics/) tutorial and got the split working on box2d bodies, but I can't get the sprites to split correctly. So what I want is for the body to have a sprite, and the sprite to split the same way the body does, I'm using PolygonSprite and the sprites split in the correct shapes and move at the same time with the bodies, but there's an offset in the image and also it seems that every time I make a cut it will just cut the original texture with no rotation. Here's what I get:

Before I make a cut:
[image]

After the first cut (notice that the small triangle is not the top right corner of the original image, and also the image is not centered correctly):
[image]

And after I cut the small triangle (notice how it rotated back and didn't cut the actual image):
[image]

Here is the method in which I split the object:

```
private void createSlice(Array<Vector2> vertices, int numVertices, Body affectedBody) {
    Vector2 center = findCentroid(vertices, vertices.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        vertices.get(i).sub(center);
    }

    BodyDef sliceBody = new BodyDef();
    sliceBody.position.set(center.x, center.y);
    sliceBody.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    PolygonShape slicePoly = new PolygonShape();
    float[] verticesArray = new float[vertices.size * 2];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < verticesArray.length; i+=2) {
        verticesArray[i] = vertices.get(j).x;
        verticesArray[i+1] = vertices.get(j++).y;
    }
    slicePoly.set(verticesArray);

    FixtureDef sliceFixture = new FixtureDef();
    sliceFixture.shape = slicePoly;
    sliceFixture.density = 1;

    Body worldSlice = mWorld.createBody(sliceBody);
    worldSlice.createFixture(sliceFixture);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        vertices.get(i).add(center);
    }

    // create polygon sprite
    float[] scaledVertices = new float[verticesArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < verticesArray.length; i++) {
        scaledVertices[i] = verticesArray[i] * Constants.BOX_TO_WORLD;
    }
    short[] triangles = mTriangulator.computeTriangles(scaledVertices).toArray();
    TextureRegion bodyPolyTexReg = ((PolygonSprite) affectedBody.getUserData()).getRegion().getRegion();
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(bodyPolyTexReg, scaledVertices, triangles);
    PolygonSprite polySprite = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    polySprite.setOrigin(0, 0);

    // set the sprite as the body's user data
    worldSlice.setUserData(polySprite);
}
```

My guess is that I would have to rotate the vertices to 0 degrees, make the cut, and then rotate them back, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks!